# SwiftUI - ScrollViewProxy scrollTo Animation Disappear in iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-animation

In the following code snippet, I use `proxy.scrollTo()` to scroll to a target. In order to animate the scrolling process, I wrapped this function call inside `withAnimation`. This code works on iOS 16, but not on iOS 17. In iOS 17, it does scroll, but without any animation. Is this a bug or is there an API change? Thanks!

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List {
                Button("Scroll") {
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(15, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
                
                ForEach(1..<50) { i in
                    Text("Item \(i)")
                        .id(i)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap your ```proxy.scrollTo``` inside a ```DispatchQueue.main.async { }```

Comment: @devdchaudhary I tried, the animation is still missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue just got fixed in iOS 17.0 build 21A5319a (Developer Beta 7). Animation is back for the scrollTo action.

Comment: I don't see scrolling animation in Beta 8 when running on Apple Watch.

Comment: I think we need to wrap it into `withAnimation { }`

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that has been addressed in iOS 17 beta 5. Your code now scrolls with animation again.

Comment: I am running iOS 17.0 build 21A5312c is the official Beta 6 on iPhone 13 Pro Max and this is still an issue, unfortunately.

Comment: I also faced this issue and I've installed the latest iOS 17 beta (08/22/23) and this issue is still here.

Comment: The issue just got fixed in iOS 17.0 build 21A5319a (Developer Beta 7)

Answer (score -1):

Okay so turns out there's been a deprecation in the API, `ScrollViewReader` is now deprecated and replaced with a new `.scrollPosition()` modifier.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var position: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                Button("Jump...") {
                    withAnimation {
                    position = 99
                 }
               }
                
                ForEach(0..<100) { index in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.green.gradient)
                        .frame(height: 300)
                        .id(index)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollPosition(id: $position)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see ScrollViewReader is deprecated.